# How can I execute multiple query string using IfElse?

Tags: string, vb.net, if-statement, odbc

I just want to know how to execute multiple query string using `IfElse` statement.

I have this string command and query:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' Stablish ODBC Connection
    Dim con As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WJNJPHR8TCX8P\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Fabrics;Integrated Security=True;")
    ' Query Command
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand
    Dim query1 As String = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE ClientId = ?"
    Dim query2 As String = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE FirstName = ?"
    Dim query3 As String = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE FirstName = ? AND MiddleName = ?"
    Dim query4 As String = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE ClientId = ? AND FirstName = ? AND MiddleName = ?"
    con.Open()
```

Anyone can help me on how to figure this out?

Thank you for advance! :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want all the 4 queries to be executed? Or only one of them to be executed? What is happening now with your code, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want the 4 queries to be executed but I don't really know to use `IfElse` statement.

Comment: My code right now is giving me an error says **"** Error Count field or syntax error **"**

Comment: Can you help me on how to use `IfElse` statement? :)

Comment: I'm expecting to happen is when I input the value of each query I got the result displaying in `GridView` For example : `ClientId=15` it will give me the result in `GridView`.

Comment: In your post, you have this line `Dim querystring As String = String.Concat(query1, query2, query3, query4)`. Then you have checks like this `If querystring Is query1 Then`... All of these checks will fail, because your querystring is the concatenation of the 4 queries.

Comment: Okay got it. By the way can you give me an example? So that I can review it. :)

Comment: Example that prevent using `String.Concat`

Comment: Tell me your business scenario.. why are you trying to concatenate? What is your overall objective?

Comment: My only objective is to execute all 4 queries. And about `String.Concat` and concatenate I don't trying to concatenate something I just want to declare and allocate all 4 query.

Comment: As the result of these queries aren't similar, treat each query separately. Execute one query at time, use its return value and plot it on a grid, then take up the next one and so on.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks! :) @arunGeorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat each query separately. Execute one query at time, use its return value and plot it on a grid, then take up the next one and so on.